# Sram/Avid brake hose compatiblity

Tags: brakes, compatibility

I have Sram Rival AXS which I want to transfer from one bike to another. Unfortunately the new bike is bigger (M -> XL) so new brake hose is required. SRAM recommends SRAM Brake Hose Kit - Double Compression | 2000mm - AC-HYD-DCMP-A1 | 00.5318.036.000 (https://www.bike24.com/p2720439.html), which is sometimh absolutly not available anywhere here. They’re also saying that any SRAM Hydraulic brake hose will work when correct olive and barb used. So can I use Avid Hydraulic brake hose 00.5016.168.010 (https://www.bike24.com/p229494.html?sku=111552) with stealth-a-majig T8 barb and red olive (https://www.bike24.com/p2199967.html)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like “Double Compression” means you can trim the kit at either end of the hose and as you mention from [the docs](https://www.sram.com/en/service/articles/SRAM-Brake-Hose-Overview)

> Can't locate a Double Compression kit? Fear not, any SRAM Hydraulic Brake Hose kit can be substituted once the respective Banjos have been removed

Both sets are suitable for use in a DOT fluid environment so the available set should be fine for your use.

I wonder if you need the Stealth-a-majig couplings as they seem focused on easier setup and improved cable routing but that’s a choice for you.